# Endless loops in Bash script using Functions and if statements

Tags: bash, function, shell, loops, if-statement

Trying to understand what is happening here and why?

The function named "why" gets called first then then the results should be either another call to the function or a complete exit. The expected results is never being able to run the loop below the if statement, which could be an if-else-fi statement or if-elif-else-fi and does not matter.

The question is why does it echo end?

I do not understand why the last echo is ever able to be called.

```
why ()  {
  read -p 'Loop now?  [y/n]' answer
      case $answer in
        y | Y | yes | YES ) answer="y";;
        *) exit;;
       esac
}

if [ $answer = 'y' ]
then
    why
fi
why 
echo "End"
```

Comment: Another way to achieve an infinite loop: `while true; do ...; done`

Comment: This is a simple magic trick: attention is diverted by funny user interaction and useless blah blah saying that loops are looping but actually no loop is involved.

Comment: Magic trick is not the answer there is an answer to the question and I hope that someone presents it...though their is alot of blah blah in the question since I first asked it as I've documented other information at the same time...you are right though the question really does not involve a loop at all, at least I know you took the interest to actually understand the question. Are you able to answer it? Please and thank you.

Comment: The blah blah I refered to was the one displayed by the running script, not your documented question. Actually the first part of the script up to the first `echo` has no purpose but entertaining the user. You can safely suppress it.

Comment: well in a way I have gotten to mentioning a lot in this question that is not part of the actual question rather it is an attempt to prevent incorrect answers before they get posted. Though I added yet another code block to the bottom of the question trying to clarify what I am not understanding as I expect the combination of the function and the if statement to cause an infinite loop never allowing the `echo` statement to be called

Comment: should be easier to understand now

Comment: This is actually an interesting question, not sure why it was closed.  maybe the example can be slimmed down a bit ... it could really only be like four or five lines tops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement considers it self done at the time the function completes. It is better shown in this example and the script will not loop back to the echo start.

```
echo start
why ()  {
  read -p 'Loop now?  [y/n]' answer
      case $answer in
        y | Y | yes | YES ) answer="y";;
        *) echo 'Invalid response -- exiting now'
           exit;;
       esac
}

answer=y

if [ $answer = 'y' ]
then

    why
    echo "Ok done running the if statement ready to exit the condition now"
fi
```

So to loop back and forth a function to wrap the if statement is used as shown here:

```
echo start
why ()  {
  read -p 'Loop now?  [y/n]' answer
      case $answer in
        y | Y | yes | YES ) answer="y";;
        n | N | no | NO ) answer="n";;
        *) echo 'Invalid response -- exiting now'
           exit;;
       esac
  ifFunction
}

ifFunction () { 
  if [ $answer = 'y' ]
  then

    why
    echo "yes"
  elif [ $answer = 'n' ]
  then
    echo "to bad looping anyway"
    why
  else
    echo "else nothing but another question"
    why
  fi
}
why
echo never
```

So the answer is it has completed the function and now moves on through the script as expected, which in the example provided would have echoed end as the next task to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a loop around the part of the program where you call `why`. Did you mean this?

```
while true; do
  why ">" y n
  if [ $answer = y ]; then
    do something
  else
    do something else
  fi
done
echo "I'll never get here"
```

Comment: This is a solution to a problem but did not answer the asked question of why/how...